# Selenium ITestAnnotation

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have this code, how can I change in the condition (if) "test1" for a parameter?
I don´t know how call this class introducing the value "test1" from a parameter in @AfterMethod

```
public class Transformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass,Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod){      
       if (testMethod.getName().equals("test1")){
            System.out.println("Disable " + testMethod.getName());
            annotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I don´t know how call this class introducing the value "test1" from a parameter in @AfterMethod` don't get what exactly you want. Please provide the code you have and more detailed explanation

Comment: I have all the tests with the annotation "@Test(enabled=false)" and I want just enable one test, give the name of the method executing testng.xml

Comment: why are you referring to the @AfterMethod - if anything I believe you would need to enable/disable a test in a BeforeMethod. Are you setting up a testng.xml file where you are registering your Transformer?

Answer (score 0):

If I right understood, you want something like this:

```
public class Transformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
  String name;

  // create constructor with 'testName' as parameter
  public Transformer(String testName){
    this.name = testName;
  }

  @Override
  public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass,Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod){
    if (testMethod.getName().equals(name)){
      System.out.println("Disable " + testMethod.getName());
      annotation.setEnabled(false);
    }
  }
}
```

and you can call this class like this:

```
Transformer transformer = new Transformer("testName");
transformer.transform(...);
```

***EDIT:*** or you can do like this:

```
public class Transformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass,Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod, String testName){      
       if (testMethod.getName().equals(testName)){
            System.out.println("Disable " + testMethod.getName());
            annotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I have found similar [project](https://github.com/JavaHelper/test-ng/blob/master/testng-annotation-configurable/src/main/java/com/testng/annotation/MyTransformer.java). Probably it will be useful:

```
TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
testNG.setAnnotationTransformer(new Transformer("TestName"));
testNG.setTestClasses(new Class[] {YourTestClass.class});
testNG.run();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but, when I write: Transformer transformer = new Transformer("testName");
  transformer.transform(annotation, testClass, testConstructor, testMethod); What are the parameters annotation, testClass, testConstructor and testMethod?

Comment: `What are the parameters annotation, testClass, testConstructor and testMethod` -> I don't know. It is your code ;). PS I have added also a second suggestion, please have a look.

Comment: @BillyMartinez i have added additional information, please have a look.